# PHP mysql how can i insert an url using tinymce

Tags: php, mysql, implode

I have this kinda little problem using tinymce:
When I'm using the insert image/photo, because it asks the complete url when I upload the image/photo.

Here's the text from mysql database when it was inserted:

```
<p>In mei 2012 is de Gijsbrecht aangekleed met mooie Hanging Basquets. Deze bloembakken, die bevestigd zijn aan de lichtmasten, zijn een fleurige aankleding van de straat!&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><img src="upload/gijs.jpg" alt="" width="400" height="266" /></p>
```

Now on the image `<img src=''>` you can only see the `upload/gijs.jpg`, but what I did is insert it with complete url.

How can I implode it when inserting to the database?

My codes for insert:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['Save'] ) ) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $t_u_c = $_POST['title_up_content'];
    $u_c = $_POST['upcontent'];
    $t_c1 = $_POST['title_col1'];
    $c1 = $_POST['column1'];
    $t_c2 = $_POST['title_col2'];
    $c2 = $_POST['column2'];

    $sql_insert_home = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO jon_homepage VALUE('', '$email', '$t_u_c', '$u_c', '$t_c1', '$c1', '$t_c2', '$c2', NOW() )" ) or die ( mysql_error() );
    echo "<div id='successful'>You've successfully save data.</div>";
}
```

`$c1 = $_POST['column1'];` this is the text from the image
My website is http://www.degijsbrecht.nl/gijsbrecht/

Thanks everyone

Comment: Your example is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/). Please use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to force TinyMCE to use absolute urls instead of relative urls, and to do this you need to add the next 3 lines in your `tinyMCE.init({});` like this:

```
    tinyMCE.init({
        relative_urls : false,
        remove_script_host : false,
        convert_urls : false
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, TinyMCE is replacing absolute URLs with relative ones when you are inserting the image. This has nothing to do with your SQL code.

I think what you need to look at is [the configuration of TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration), such as the [relative_urls](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3arelative_urls) option.